# Skew Input Border Without Skewing Text Inside

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a text `input` that I'd like to skew using `transform:`skewX()`. I want to have the input's borders skewed, while keeping the text inside un-skewed.

[image]

Here's the code that I've tried:

```css
#search{
    border:2px solid #323232;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding:3px 10px;
    -moz-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   -webkit-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   transform: skewX(-40deg);
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
   -moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
   transform: skewX(40deg); 
}

:-moz-placeholder { 
   -moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
   transform: skewX(40deg);   
}

::-moz-placeholder {  
   -moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
   transform: skewX(40deg);  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   -moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
   transform: skewX(40deg); 
}
```

```html
 <form id="search-form" action="/idee" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: I am afraid to say so, but you can't. I suggest instead you use value="Search" to do so

Comment: Put your input inside a div and place the border onto that div and skew that and it the input text is still skewed then do the opposite skew to the input so it straightens it back up. also you would need to remove the border of the input. Or just use a background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

We need to add another layer. In this case, I'd typically use a `label` element, wrapped around the `input`. We can give that outer `label` the border, and then skew it. Then we skew the inner `input` the exact opposite amount.

---

### Code

```css
#search {
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid #323232;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding:3px 10px;
    -moz-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   -webkit-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(-40deg);
   transform: skewX(-40deg);
}
#search input {
    border:0;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -webkit-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(40deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(40deg);
   transform: skewX(40deg);
}
```

```html
 <form id="search-form" action="/idee" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
                <label id="search"><input type="text" placeholder="Search" /></label>
</form>
```

---

#### Extra

I misunderstood your question initially and thought that you wanted the border to be skewed, and the placeholder text also skewed, but the final actual text NOT skewed. This is a bit more complex, but can be done, and since I already got it figured out, I'll just leave a Codepen link here: **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Kelderic/pen/EjgXbM)**

Comment: i was about to give the same answer to remind the use of label ... it is good to read the manual sometimes . http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html & http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted to do !

Comment: Milleto, just to be clear, my main answer was what you wanted, right, not the extra Codepen that I linked to?

Comment: Yes, your main answer was what i wanted

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more clear what you want, in case others have the same problem in the future.