# Removing Skew Effect from Text Inside Input Fields with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Settings Page</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Eraser&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Eraser', sans-serif;
        }

        /* Adjust button style */
        .rounded-none {
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Adjust skew for all divs */
        .skew-div {
            transform: skewX(-40deg);
        }

        /* Counteract skew for text */
        .skew-text {
            transform: skewX(40deg);
        }

        /* Adjust skew for text in input fields */
        input.skew-text {
            transform: skewX(0deg);
        }
        


        /* Skew the button */
        .skew-button {
            transform: skewX(-40deg); /* Adjust the skew angle as needed */
        }

        /* Counter-skew the text inside the button */
        .skew-button .unskew-text {
            display: block; /* Make span behave like a block element to center the text correctly */
            transform: skewX(40deg); /* Apply the opposite skew transformation */
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body class="bg-gray-800 text-white">
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto py-10">

        <div class="text-center text-2xl font-bold mb-6">Settings</div>
        <div class="grid gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
            <!-- Settings Group 1 -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Columns -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Columns</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>

                <!-- Rows -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Rows</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Settings Group 2 -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Tile Height -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Tile Height</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
                <!-- Tile Width -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Tile Width</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Password</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Default Formatting -->
            <div class="text-center text-2xl font-bold my-4">Default Formatting</div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Font Size -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Font Size</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
                <!-- Font Color -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Font Color</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Background Color -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Background Color</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
                <!-- Font Family -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Font Family</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Hotkeys -->
            <div class="text-center text-2xl font-bold my-4">Hotkeys</div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Update | Ctrl+U</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Rollback | Ctrl+Z</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Reset | Ctrl+R</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Roll-forward | Ctrl+Y</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Edit Taskboard | Ctrl+E</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Open Taskboard | Ctrl+O</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Save Button -->
            <button class="bg-blue-500 mt-10 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-none w-1/3 mx-auto skew-button">
                <span class="unskew-text">Save</span>
            </button>
            

            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm working on a web page where I apply a skew effect to certain div elements using CSS to create a distinctive visual style. Inside these skewed `divs`, I have `<input>` elements for user inputs. Although I want the `divs` to remain skewed, I aim to display the text inside the input fields without the skew effect, ensuring it's easy to read.

Despite using `transform: skewX(0deg);` for the input elements to counteract the skew effect, the text inside the inputs still appears skewed. I've tried increasing the specificity of my CSS selectors and ensuring there are no conflicting styles, but the issue persists.

Question:

How can I remove the skew effect from the text inside the input fields while keeping the skew effect on the surrounding `divs`? Is there a more effective CSS strategy or a specific property I should use to achieve this?

Comment: One way is to "mirror" data from input field into a `div` and display that `div` over top of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `40deg` instead of `0deg`:

```
input.skew-text {
    transform: skewX(40deg);
}
```

Unfortunately, if you wanted to target only the text and not also the edge of the input, I don't think you can do that.
I hope this resolve your the problem :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Settings Page</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Eraser&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Eraser', sans-serif;
        }

        /* Adjust button style */
        .rounded-none {
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Adjust skew for all divs */
        .skew-div {
            transform: skewX(-40deg);
        }

        /* Counteract skew for text */
        .skew-text {
            transform: skewX(40deg);
        }

        /* Adjust skew for text in input fields */
        input.skew-text {
            transform: skewX(40deg);
        }
        


        /* Skew the button */
        .skew-button {
            transform: skewX(-40deg); /* Adjust the skew angle as needed */
        }

        /* Counter-skew the text inside the button */
        .skew-button .unskew-text {
            display: block; /* Make span behave like a block element to center the text correctly */
            transform: skewX(40deg); /* Apply the opposite skew transformation */
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body class="bg-gray-800 text-white">
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto py-10">

        <div class="text-center text-2xl font-bold mb-6">Settings</div>
        <div class="grid gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
            <!-- Settings Group 1 -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Columns -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Columns</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>

                <!-- Rows -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Rows</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Settings Group 2 -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Tile Height -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Tile Height</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
                <!-- Tile Width -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Tile Width</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Password</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Default Formatting -->
            <div class="text-center text-2xl font-bold my-4">Default Formatting</div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Font Size -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Font Size</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
                <!-- Font Color -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Font Color</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <!-- Background Color -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Background Color</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
                <!-- Font Family -->
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-500 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <div class="flex-1 flex items-center"> <!-- Adjusted to take up half width -->
                        <span class="skew-text text-black">Font Family</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" value="10" class="w-16 bg-blue-300 text-black rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-opacity-50 skew-text text-center" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Hotkeys -->
            <div class="text-center text-2xl font-bold my-4">Hotkeys</div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Update | Ctrl+U</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Rollback | Ctrl+Z</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Reset | Ctrl+R</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Roll-forward | Ctrl+Y</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2"> <!-- Reduce spacing between divs -->
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Edit Taskboard | Ctrl+E</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-300 px-4 skew-div rounded-none" style="height: 30px;"> <!-- Add skew-div class -->
                    <span class="skew-text text-black">Open Taskboard | Ctrl+O</span>
                    <span class="skew-text"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Save Button -->
            <button class="bg-blue-500 mt-10 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-none w-1/3 mx-auto skew-button">
                <span class="unskew-text">Save</span>
            </button>
            

            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually no! I want the input fields to be skewy, but the text inside them to not be skewy!

Comment: As I said, you can't. You could try the workaround wrapping the input with a div and skew that, then make the input someway transparent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374196/skew-input-border-without-skewing-text-inside